# Configuring Propel to Work with Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, configuration

I'm trying to build a plugin using Propel ORM to be used in a multisite envivroment. Currenly it works in single great but I can't figure out how to get it to create the tables for each site and have the plugin connect to those tables for one code base